# How secure is Laravel's encrypt and decrypt helpers?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I wanted to ask, I'm building an app that requires the info stored in the database to be encrypted in a way that the users of the app can see that same encrypted data, but decrypted.

I know laravel provides encryption and decryption helpers, but I wanted to know how secure they are. If someone for some reason has access to the database, could they decrypt that info by making their own laravel project or something like that?

I could manually create an encryption and decryption function that uses a secret key to correctly encrypt or decrypt the data, but reading laravel's documentation, they encourage users to use laravel's built-in helpers, that's why I ask.

Comment: Unless they also have access to your encryption key, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel use AES-256 encryption. It uses **APP_KEY** in .env file. You must have to protect it from getting into malicious hands. Also store it securely otherwise if you lost it, you won't be able to decrypt your data again.

Here is some description about AES-256 and how hard is to brute force it, you can refer to this [link](https://scrambox.com/article/brute-force-aes/#:%7E:text=On%20average%2C%20to%20brute%2Dforce,simply%202255%20%2F%202%2C117.8%20trillion.) for more details.

On average, to brute-force attack AES-256, one would need to try 2<sup>255</sup> keys. (This is the total size of the key space divided by 2, because on average, you'll find the answer after searching half the key space.) So the time taken to perform this attack, measured in years, is simply 2<sup>255</sup> / 2,117.8 trillion.

Comment: It's worth nothing Laravel only supports natively AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC encryption. If you need to use another encryption by default, you only need to implement 
 [the Encrypter contract](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Encryption/Encrypter.html) and rebind the 'encrypter' alias in a service provider.

Comment: I guess, the question is about how secure the laravel native encryption is.